# How to import database file without sql file?

Tags: mysql, database, wampserver

I have Wamp server and i have a database file ,but i don't have the sql file for this database.
I want to import this database , i tried to copy the file into "C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.9\data" file , but its not work.
Is there any way to import this data without the sql file ?

Comment: What version of MYSQL was being used when the database was created? Was it also created using MYSQL5.7.9?

Comment: Is your database a MYISAM or INNODB type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it is myisam, it is proabalby possible using the method you tried. But there is no way this can work with an innodb database.

innodb store informations in a file common to multiple databases.